# Is there a way to 'just' select the stuff 'inside' the marquee selection box?

Tags: modeling

I'm pretty sure there's not, but by asking, maybe it can be willed into existence. :)

...is there a way to 'just' select the stuff 'inside' the marquee selection box?
That is, not the stuff that marquee selection box crosses.

[image]

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Scroll in closer and be more accurate! :^)

Comment: I would have thought the 'Tweak' tool was better for selection, here, in Object mode? (In Edit mode, only enclosed elements are box-selected) Although I did think 3DS's distinction between [top-left to bottom-right] box selections and [top-right to bottom-left]  box selections was quite clever.. a distinction Blender could copy very nicely.